# How to Fetch User images from Instagram by its API

Tags: ios, instagram

I can't find any tutorial in iOS to fetch the images from [instagram](http://instagram.com/developer) by its API. I saw [that](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/),
but can't find any interesting. So please tell me is it possible to fetch the user images from  Instagram? If Yes then please send me the link or any code which can be helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you look at [Instagram Objective C Library](https://github.com/jstart/Instagram) which may help you to port it to iOS.

Comment: i don't want to make an app like instagram .. i just want to fetch the image from instagram....otherwise this project is for MAC.

Comment: Of course, that is Mac project. I am not saying you to use whole code for mentioned library. You can take the requesting API code form the mentioned code and use them in your application. At the end this Objective C code.

Comment: is this for fetch the images from instagram

Comment: Please spend some time looking at the code , you will get to know. :)

Comment: Check [InstagramClient.m](https://github.com/jstart/Instagram/blob/master/Instagram/InstagramClient.m) file inside the source code.

Comment: Did you find it useful for you?

Comment: The GitHub repository you guys are refering to doesn't exists anymore... (404 Error)